# Can not configure Keycloak 17 in spring boot app - elements [keycloak.keycloak.bearer-only] were left unbound

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I need to disable login page Keycloak redirect in Spring Boot app, this are my configurations:

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8091
  connection-timeout: 6000
keycloak:
  enabled: true
  bearer-only: true
  auth-server-url: http://localhost:8484/auth
  realm: test-realm
  resource: my-test-client
  keycloak.bearer-only: true
  use-resource-role-mappings: false
```

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);

        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().sessionManagement().

                sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/users/unprotected-data").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/users/create").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/users/signin").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

    }
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
    }

    @Autowired
    public KeycloakClientRequestFactory keycloakClientRequestFactory;

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public KeycloakRestTemplate keycloakRestTemplate(){
        return new KeycloakRestTemplate(keycloakClientRequestFactory);
    }
}
```

but I have an error configuration message that KeycloakSpringBootProperties cannot bi binded to ConfigurationProperties:

```
Description:

Binding to target [Bindable@7bb35cc6 type = org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootProperties, value = 'provided', annotations = array<Annotation>[@org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties(ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=false, prefix=keycloak, value=keycloak)]] failed:

    Property: keycloak.keycloak.bearer-only
    Value: true
    Origin: class path resource [application.yml] - 10:25
    Reason: The elements [keycloak.keycloak.bearer-only] were left unbound.

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

What would be the right way to update configuration ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As much as I know,

Its either `keycloak.bearer-only: true` or

```
keycloak:
bearer-only: true
```

Which are both equal.

But what your trying to do is `keycloak.keycloak.bearer-only: true` which is incorrect.

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48601044/spring-boot-keycloak-bearer-only-for-backend-service-not-working) that might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

The auth server url in the keycloak v17 it's http://localhost:${port number} without /auth , you can check here for the spring boot adapter configuration https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_spring_boot_adapter
also it's `keycloak.bearer-only=true` and not `keycloak.keycloak.bearer-only=true`